# SQL Database - Taking one columns max value for another table column

Tags: mysql, database-design, groupwise-maximum

I design my database and have 3 tables:

1) `Authors` table has ID, Name, Surname, and Paper_ID.
Name and Surname combination is unique.

2) `Topics` table has TopicName, SOTAResult, and Paper_ID.
TopicName, SOTAResult are unique.

3) `Papers` table has Title(unique), Result, Abstract.

I design it like that way because a paper has multiple authors and multiple topics but one result.
My question is, I want to assign max value from results column in Papers table to SOTAResult column in Topics table. 
In more clearly SOTAResult should be the max value of Result of Papers wrt one topic.
I also wonder did I build correctly this database according to my necessity or should I change something specifically.

Comment: I anticipate having paper_id in Authors will cause problems especially since name and surname combination is unique - that implies an author can only have one paper. Same may apply to Topics. Consider adding junction tables for paper_author and Paper_topics.

Comment: How should I handle the Authors-Papers one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Remove `paper_id` from the `authors` table, because an author doesn't have only one paper. Instead add `author_id` to the `papers` table, because each paper belongs to one author, or so I understand this. But how do topics relate to authors and papers? Is there supposed to be an m:n relation to papers, e.g. topics are 'maths', 'physics', and 'chemistry' and paper #1 treats 'maths' and ' physics', while paper #2 treats 'physics' and 'chemistry'?

Comment: A one-to_many table is also a many_to_one table depending on how you use it. BTW I see this DB as being primarily about papers and their attributes, Your view may be that it's about authors and what they have done and that would colour the design approach.

Comment: Yes you are totaly right! I should look for the many-to-many relationship for author-paper and paper-topic relations. The relation is let's say there are papers p1,p2 and p3. Also there are authors a1,a2,a3 and a1 writes p1; a2 writes p1,p3; a3 writes p2,p3. Moreover there are topics t1,t2,t3 and p1 has topics t1,t3; p2  has t2,t3; p3 has t1,t2,t3. Also each paper has only 1 result(int). This result should be transfer to all topics of this paper so that SOTAResult wrt this topic can be found. t1 has SOTA1, t2 has SOTA2 etc.

Comment: Follow the groupwise-maximum tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an m:n relation between authors and papers: One author can write many papers and one paper can be written by many authors. You achive this with a bridge table:

- table `author (author_id, first_name, last_name, ...)` <= with unique constraint on `first_name` + `last_name`, primary key is `author_id`
- table `paper (paper_id, title, result, ...)` <= with unique constraint on `tiltle`, primary key is `paper_id`
- table `author_paper (author_id, paper_id)` <= with unique constraint on `author_id` + `paper_id`

You also want an m:n relation between papers and topics:

- table `topic (topic_id, name, ...)` <= with unique constraint on `name`, primary key is `topic_id`
- table `paper_topic (paper_id, topic_id)` <= with unique constraint on `paper_id` + `topic_id`

You wouldn't store results redundantly. If you want to know what maximum result a topic achieved, you select this with joins, e.g.:

```
select t.name as topic_name, max(p.result) as max_result
from paper_topic pt
join paper p using (paper_id)
join topic t using (topic_id)
group by t.name
order by t.name;
```

Comment: Very detailed and great design. I wonder how to insert new value to topic table? Do you have a column called sota or you get it from the select statement?

Comment: As mentioned, you shouldn't store data redundantly. If a topic's sota is the maximum result over all its papers, then just select it. It's already in the database (in the paper table), so all you have to do is select it as shown. So, inserting a new topic is just that: an insert into the topic table. Then you may add some paper (with an insert into the paper table). And then you may relate paper and topic (with an insert into the paper_topic table). And if you want to know the topic's sota, you select it by joining the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a PapersAuthors table to facilitate Authors having multiple Papers. I'd add a TopicsPapers table so a topic can have multiple papers and a paper can be in multiple topics. If a paper shouldn't be in multiple topics then don't have TopicsPapers and put a topic_id in Papers.

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve with SOTAResult but I believe you want to find the "best paper" for a topic. In that case move SOTAResult to Papers and find it using a "limit 1 subquery":

```
SELECT t.*, (SELECT paper_id FROM Papers AS tp WHERE tp.topic_id=t.topic_id ORDER BY SOTAResult DESC LIMIT 1) AS top_paper FROM Topics AS t;
```

Comment: Yes I want to show the best paper but also I must keep the SOTA values in my database. SOTA is the highest value wrt all results from Papers in a particular topic. You are suggesting add column SOTAResult to Papers but in this case i think Topic wouldn't has a SOTA attribute.

Comment: Does that mean the SOTAResult column would actually be SOTA and also you need TopicsPapers and to have SOTA in it so different papers can have different SOTA's for different Topics? If so I'll rewrite it my answer.